# Fake time zone for web app testing

Tags: internationalization, timezone

I have a web app and some people in Asia are seeing some weird time zone issues with the dates in the program. Is there a way to fake chrome or firefox or IE to pretend like my computer's timezone is like theirs so I can debug the issues easily?

Answer (score 14):

Sure: launch the browser from the command line with a customized `TZ` environment variable instead of the way you normally run it:

```
TZ=Japan firefox &
```

Make sure firefox isn't already running when you launch it like this because if it is already running then it will probably just open a new window under the existing instance of the browser instead of starting a new instance.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using command line? E.g. is there a way to do this using chrome flags (e.g. `--TZ` which I tried but didn't work)?

Comment: I don't think any applications provide a command line option for this since it's pretty trivial to use the environment variable instead. Why do you need to avoid using the environment variable?

Comment: I'm trying to do it in from a Windows shortcut. (something like [--user-data-dir](https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory#TOC-Windows)).

Comment: This worked when using a command line in ubuntu, but it didn't work with from a command line in windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the system time in Windows 8 does auto change my Firefox browser timezone without reboot or relaunch of the sofware.

Comment: Works in linux too (linux mint) just changed the system timezone and loaded chrome. Used http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/ to test