# Chrome Dev Tools - GeoLocation override not working

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I want to override my GeoLocation using Chrome Dev Tools. I changed my GeoLocation to Moscow as shown in the below screenshot, but still my google search results are generated based on my actual location. I've also tried refreshing the page (Empty Cache and Hard Reload) and it still wont work.

[image: GeoLocation override - Moscow]

[I followed the steps mentioned in this Doc.](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/geolocation)

Comment: It looks like the functionality is broken in Chromium. I suggest using Firefox https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147166/how-can-you-fake-geolocation-in-firefox
or even BlueStacks4 and it's built-in location override

Answer (score -1):

Please try scrolling to the bottom of google search and clicking on 'Update Location' or 'Use precise location':

[Google search screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRGL3.png)

If that does not work, then you might have issues with permissions in your Chrome settings.
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

I recommend this answer for time zone testing:
[Is there a way to change your timezone in Chrome devtools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849770/is-there-a-way-to-change-your-timezone-in-chrome-devtools)

(edit) = Also might be worth to check you are using an accepted value for TimezoneID when adding a new custom location:
https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Supported-Time-Zone-Values_66194188

Comment: i have the same problem, none of what you suggested work for me. also, i'm using a vpn to change my ip, so it doesn"'t have to do with ip. Are you able to spoof your location with chrome devtool ?