# How is it possible to ensure that snapshot testing with Jest is run via a certain timezone?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I was creating a project and wanted to ensure that storyshots in snapshot testing are run in UTC+3. To achieve that I put process.env.TZ = 'UTC+3'; in jest.config.storyshots.js file which looks like this

```
const jestConfigCommon = require('./jest.config.common');
process.env.TZ = 'UTC+3';
module.exports = {
    ...jestConfigCommon,
    testMatch: [
        "<rootDir>/tests/storyshots.test.ts",
    ],
};
```

I am using "jest-config": "^24.9.0"

But it does not help thus I really need your help

Guys if something is not clear please let me know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set a timezone in my Jest config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261381/how-do-i-set-a-timezone-in-my-jest-config)