# How do I set a timezone in my Jest config in *Windows 10*?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

This question is similar to [How do I set a timezone in my Jest config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261381/how-do-i-set-a-timezone-in-my-jest-config) but all the answers there pertain to *nix.

How do you set the timezone for jest tests when running Windows 10?

Comment: It seems there is no way to do it without affectin system time in Windows. You could check [set-tz](https://github.com/capaj/set-tz) code for details. Upd: please take a look at [this solution](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4230#issuecomment-480749039) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK! Thanks for the comments and answers. It got me pointed in a good direction.

`set-tz` is cool but the `cleanup()` function wasn't firing when the tests completed.
That, combined with `tzutil` changing the Windows system time, forced me to think about minimizing the impact of the timezone change and having a way to *force* it back instead of relying on an exit-listener.

So, here's where it landed.

```js
// setTimezone file.

const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const os = require('os');

export const setTimezone = (TZ) => {
  if (os.platform() === 'win32') {
    process.env.STORED_TZ = execSync('tzutil /g').toString();
    execSync(`tzutil /s "${TZ}"`);
    console.warn(`Windows timezone changed from "${process.env.STORED_TZ}" to "${TZ}"\nRun \`tzutil /s "${process.env.STORED_TZ}"\` to set it back manually.`);
  } else {
    process.env.TZ = TZ;
  }
};

export const restoreTimezone = () => {
  if (os.platform() === 'win32') {
    execSync(`tzutil /s "${process.env.STORED_TZ}"`);
    console.warn(`Windows timezone restored to "${process.env.STORED_TZ}"`);
  } else {
    process.env.TZ = process.env.STORED_TZ;
  }
};
```

Here's an example of where we use it.

```js
// test file

import * as dtt from './dateTimeTools';
import typeOf from './funcs/typeOf';
import { restoreTimezone, setTimezone } from './setTimezone';

const inputs = {
  dateOnly: '2020-01-01',
  dateTimeWithoutTimezone: '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000',
  midnightNewYorkTimezone: '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000-05:00',
};

describe('dateTimeTools > isoToDate', () => {
  setTimezone('Pacific Standard Time'); // 

  assert({
    given: 'any valid ISO string.',
    should: 'return a date object.',
    actual: typeOf(dtt.isoToDate(inputs.dateOnly)),
    expected: 'date',
  });

  assert({
    given: 'a date-only ISO string.',
    should: 'return the given date at midnight in the local timezone.',
    actual: dtt.isoToDate(inputs.dateOnly).toString(),
    expected: 'Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)',
  });

  restoreTimezone(); // 
});
```

And the output.
[image: test console output]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can solve it by using [set-tz package](https://github.com/capaj/set-tz)

```js
const setTZ = require('set-tz')
setTZ('America/New_York')
```