# How to set add my own globals when using jest-preset-angular/global-setup

Tags: jestjs, jest-preset-angular

I would like to be able to set a timezone for all tests to run in globally as outlined in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261381/how-do-i-set-a-timezone-in-my-jest-config). But still setup my jest.config.ts to leverage, either directly or indirectly, `jest-preset-angular/global-setup`.

It seems there is only one place in the jest.config.ts to set a `globalSetup`.

This is what I have in my jest-global-setup.js file, which I currently have referenced in my `globalSetup` but I don't believe this is correct:

```
module.exports = async () => {
  process.env.TZ = 'UTC';

  return require('jest-preset-angular/global-setup');
};
```

Comment: does it work for you?