# javascript - how to mock timezone?

Tags: javascript, mocking, timezone

I have a function that calculates which date (YYYY-MM-DD) a given timestamp resolves to on the users local timezone. E.g.: `2019-12-31T23:30:00.000Z` resolves to `2020-01-01` on `UTC+1`, but resolves to `2019-12-31` on `UTC-1`.

This is my implementation:

```
function calcLocalYyyyMmDd(dateStr) {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  const year = String(date.getFullYear()).padStart(4, "0");
  const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
  const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
  return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
}
```

This works as expected, however, I would like to verify this behaviour in a unit test (using jest, not sure if relevant).

```
describe("calcLocalYyyyMmDd", () => {
  test("calculates correct date on UTC+1", () => {
    // TODO mock local timezone
    const result = calcLocalYyyyMmDd("2019-12-31T23:30:00.000Z");
    expect(result).toBe("2020-01-01");
  });

  test("calculates correct date on UTC-1", () => {
    // TODO mock local timezone
    const result = calcLocalYyyyMmDd("2020-01-01T00:30:00.000Z");
    expect(result).toBe("2019-12-31");
  });
});
```

How can I mock the local timezone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is [no simple way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449343/634824).

However, if you are on a Linux system you can set the `TZ` environment variable before [launching a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39533934/634824) or [starting Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35432069/634824), but once the process is running the time zone cannot be changed.  The `Date` object only uses the system's local time zone.

Note that this approach isn't reliable on Windows due to complexities of time zone implementations.

Answer (score 6):

If you're writing `jest` tests or similar, consider using https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezone-mock to enable testing your code in at least two timezones.