# How to get hour and minute as numeric values (not string) in local timezone from Javascript Date object?

Tags: javascript

I have a Date in UTC format, and want to get the hour and minute but in the local time zone the browser is running in - and without me specifying the timezone explicitly, just using the default used by the browser. I know I can get the whole date time in the local zone as a string using Date.toLocaleTimeString() or Date.toString() but don't want to have to parse out the hour and minute.

Also I can get the numeric hour and minute from a Date using Date.getHours() and getMinutes(), but this won't be in the local time zone - or will it? (ironically my local timezone is UTC so not sure how to test)

Thanks

**EDIT:** Answering my own question, see below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: *"using Date.getHours() and getMinutes(), but this won't be in the local time zone - or will it?"*: it will, but make sure you used a correct way to interpret the UTC string to make the Date instance. Just add a snippet with example input and code, so we can confirm that part of the code.

Comment: Also, [answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448754/how-to-use-a-custom-time-in-browser-to-test-for-client-vs-server-time-difference) give interesting info on how to test with a different time zone than your own.

Comment: how is your `I have a Date in UTC format` exactly, in a string ? show us a sample!

Comment: Thanks all, I've answered my own question below. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a Javascript Date object is apparently not in a timezone as such, it's basically just the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch as per Date.now() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

So what I didn't realise until I checked the docs ;-) was that Date.getHours() returns the numeric hours value according to **local** time (i.e. time in the timezone of the device running the code) and not UTC time (which I was trying to avoid). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours

So Date.hours() gives me exactly what I want (if for some reason I did want UTC, I could use Date.getUTCHours() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours

Then I can just use Date.getMinutes() to get the minute value of the Date and that's not affected by timezone anyway so all good :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `toLocalstring` and then i would convert string to number.

```js
function getNumericHourAndMinute() {
  const tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  const d = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: tz,  timeStyle: 'short', hour12: false });
  const p = d.split(':');
  
  return [Number(p[0]), Number(p[1])];
  
}
console.log(getNumericHourAndMinute());
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: @LucaKiebel You are rigth! thanks. I updated and tried with a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date.prototype.getHours` and `Date.prototype.getMinutes` to get the hours and minetes from a string date like: 2022-01-08 14:00:00.

Use this code:

```js
var d = new Date(/* A example date: '2022-01-08 14:00:00'*/);

var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();

// Whit the example date you get in the console: 'Time: 14:00.'
console.log('Time: '+ h + ' : ' + m + '.');
```

Comment: the PO did not specify the type of input date; and she is sure not a JS date type